# Getting the ssrs webservice from any given url?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, reporting-services

So I can't reference any specific SSRS web service with my project because I want users to be able to point it to their own report server.  Is there any way for me to do this?

Specifically I'm going to need to be able to (at least) get the available reports, view reports, and schedule reporting.  I haven't touched report scheduling via c# yet, but report selection/viewing is simple enough with a reference to my local reporting service.  Is there any way to dynamically load the web service for any given reporting service--assuming I know the url or the server and instance name?

```
        var rs = new ReportingService2005
            {
                Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            };

        // get catalog items from the report server database
        CatalogItem[] items = rs.ListChildren("/", true);

        // add each report to the combobox
        foreach (CatalogItem ci in items)
        {
            if (ci.Type == ItemTypeEnum.Report)
                comboBox1.Items.Add(ci.Path);
        }
```

This is what I'm currently doing to pull out the available reports.  But, as mentioned, above, it is directly referencing my own report server.  ReportingService2005 (what I named the reference to my .asmx web service) is what I would like to be able to dynamically load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely possible. ReportingServices have `.Url` property you can assign. So you can do:

```
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
rs.Url = "http://<Server Name>/reportserver/ReportService2005.asmx";
```

Reference: "[Setting the Url Property of the Web Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153652.aspx)"

Comment: So I need to specifically reference some web service and after that I can just change the URL?

Comment: @claudekennilol Exactly, that's a pretty much a standard approach when working with any classic WebService - during development you can load a local service (so a proxy class can be created) and then at runtime you can change the URL.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's my solution then ^_^.